# disable Setup from User Menu

Tags: profile, permissions, system-admin

I want to disable "Setup" Link from the user Menu.I have unchecked "View Setup and Configuration" permission from System Permissions for the profile of that particular user but Setup link is still there.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Sanshita Shah

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

From the [HELP DOCS](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214456&language=en_US&type=1)

> It is possible to hide the "Setup" link from end-users with the
>   Improved Setup User Interface.  Previously, users with minimal
>   permissions would still need access to "Setup" in order to access
>   their personal information.  If we enable the Improved Setup User
>   Interface, personal information will now be available under My
>   Settings, eliminating the need to access Setup

In order to hide the "Setup"  link, ensure that **both** are true:

1. **Enable the Improved Setup User Interface:**

   - Setup > Customize > User Interface > Enable Improved Setup User Interface
2. **Disable "View Setup and Configuration" from the users' profile(s):**

   - Setup > Manage Users > Profiles > (Profile Name) > Edit > View Setup and Configuration
   - Setup > Manage Users > Profiles > Profile Name > System Permissions > Edit > View Setup and Configuration

Also check permission sets (from your answer/comment)

Comment: Thanks @Eric, The user had a Permission set which allowed her to view the setup link, have disabled it now!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/64035)